# org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read

Tags: jmeter, tcp

Jmeter with TCP IP connection with `TCPClientImpl` basic class implementation with the following options:

```
EOL = 0D  
Re-use Connection = No   
Close Connection = No   
Set Delay = No
SO_LINGER=0
eolByte=0
```

When i run my test I'm getting response data as expected but response code is 500 with error:

> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the details of your server, request and response it is very hard to come up with suitable [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) configuration.

You can try using [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) which might be easier to configure. As per its [documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/#Advantages-of-Raw-Request)

> - really full control over request data
> - option to send file contents directly to network (lower memory usage on big files)
> - option to limit response data stored in results (lower memory consumption)
> - **actually it is raw TCP sampler**, so you can try to test non-HTTP servers

HTTP Raw Request sampler can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

As a last resort you can always use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Socket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) class to send a TCP request to your server like:

```
def client = new Socket('your TCP server IP or Hostname', your TCP server port);
client.setSoTimeout(2000);
client << "Hello ";
client.withStreams { input, output ->
    def reader = input.newReader()
    def response = reader.readLine()
    log.info('Response = ' + response)
}
client.close()
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter TCP with Groovy]